# Asp Identity associate a new entity with its user

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working with a quick demo in which I use Asp Identities to handle authentication, along with a bearer token.

I created a Comments Entity as such:

```
public class CommentModel
{
    public IdentityUser User { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public String Text { get; set; }
}
```

With the context:

```
public class AuthContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
{
    public DbSet<CommentModel> Comments { get; set; }
    public AuthContext() : base("WebDatabase")
    {

    }
}
```

Controller method:

```
[Authorize]
    // POST: api/Comments
    [ResponseType(typeof(CommentModel))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostCommentModel(CommentModel commentModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        commentModel.User = await _repo.FindUser(User.Identity.GetUserName());
        db.Comments.Add(commentModel);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = commentModel.ID }, commentModel);
    }
```

Token generation:

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {

        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });

        using (AuthRepository _repo = new AuthRepository())
        {
            IdentityUser user = await _repo.FindUser(context.UserName, context.Password);

            if (user == null)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                return;
            }
        }

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", context.UserName));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "user"));

        context.Validated(identity);

    }
```

I then created a CommentsController and I am trying to within the post method when the user submits a CommentModel the user field will be = to the current user. However, when I do something like, `commentModel.User = await _repo.FindUser(User.Identity.GetUserName());` The variable passed into FindUser is always null, I have also tried using `User.Identity.GetUserId()`.

Comment: Are you sure you're logged in when doing this?

Comment: I can get into the method, I have the [Authorize] attribute set to wouldn't that prevent me from getting deeper into the method?

Comment: What does `User.Identity.GetUserId()` return?

Comment: It returns a null value.

Comment: What happens if you try browsing in an incognito window?

Comment: I will try that now, I am using the Chrome extension Servistate to help me do requests.

Comment: I tried using incognito however my extension just keeps opening in the main window.

Comment: So what cookies are you sending in the Servistate addon?

Comment: It says none when I browse to that section of the addon.

Comment: If you're not sending cookies, you cannot be logged in... What headers are you sending?

Comment: Then why does my method let me access it deeper if I am not authorized?